# file permission errors with all containers on docker host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, unknown-host

I have a a few images a tibco , weblogic & spring boot etc that suddenly started failing on some of our linux server after a patching cycle because they cant determine the hostname of the container.

I have a docker swarm with one master and one worker. 
If I deploy these services on both nodes, the one starts successful and on the other I get an unknown host error infact any image that somehow references localhost fails on my worker machine.

It appears that on the machine that it fails on the user cant view the /etc/resolv.conf file and the /etc/host file and because of this ping localhost isn't working. But I have no idea how to fix this, and because it works on some server and other not I don't think its a code issue

Error on tibco container

```
Version 7.0.1 V4 2/27/2013

2018-09-30 11:40:01.095 FATAL: Could not resolve hostname '5802dab65aea'. Possibly default hostname is not configured properly while multiple network interfaces are present.
2018-09-30 11:40:01.095 FATAL: Exception in startup, exiting.
```

Exception on weblogic domain

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: d718d565dee5: d718d565dee5: Temporary failure in name resolution

Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: d718d565dee5: d718d565dee5: Temporary failure in name resolution

Stopping Derby server...
```

logging into the container on the host that is faulty

```
   sh-4.2$ hostname
    b73fe493e913
    sh-4.2$ ping b73fe493e913
    ping: unknown host b73fe493e913
    sh-4.2$ ping localhost
    ping: unknown host localhost
    sh-4.2$ cat /etc/hosts
    cat: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
    sh-4.2$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
    cat: /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied
    sh-4.2$ ls -ltr
-rw-r-----+  1 root root    174 Sep 30 13:20 hosts
-rw-r-----+  1 root root     13 Sep 30 13:20 hostname
-rw-r-----+  1 root root    148 Sep 30 13:20 resolv.conf
```

Logging into the container on the working machine

```
    sh-4.2$ hostname
    2925d3058c7f
    sh-4.2$ ping 2925d3058c7f
    ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
    sh-4.2$ ping localhost
    ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
    sh-4.2$ cat /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
    10.0.0.252      2925d3058c7f
    sh-4.2$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
    search *.co.za *.holdings.co.za **.co.za *.corp *.com *.co.za
    nameserver 127.0.0.11
    options ndots:0
sh-4.2$ ls -ltr
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    174 Sep 30 08:48 hosts
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     13 Sep 30 08:48 hostname
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    148 Sep 30 08:48 resolv.conf
```

Docker info

```
Containers: 112
 Running: 18
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 94
Images: 388
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: nfg2fjye8i8ub1cx0jmgkb75x
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 172.22.141.179
 Manager Addresses:
  172.30.10.35:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 62.74GiB
Name: #######
ID: O23F:WZTF:GV4Z:7WXU:3BI6:TY46:MIMR:JW6M:XPG4:XNWI:TO7H:CNZB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:23:03 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:25:29 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: My guess is an selinux policy is blocking things.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed it 
The linux administrator did a ls -ald on /var/lib/docker/*
And found the /var/lib/docker/containers directory was marked wit a drwxr-x---+
When  we removed it the issue was resolved

Comment: You should specify HOW to remove the issue.  What's the correct setting?  Why it happened to be wrong?